# Why delete a well rated accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, rejection-reasons

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762995/how-to-use-star-rating-of-font-awesome-with-django) had nearly 9000 hits so its quite popular and many Django web developers would like to know how to utilize Fontawesome.

Over a year ago I had come across the opensource project Raty and given it as an answer.
The answer was well perceived with +9 votes.

Yet today the answer was deleted by a moderator.
How is this helpful to the community?

[image]

Comment: It's nothing but a link only answer.  [We don't really like those here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)  The fact that the link is dead would also increase the likelihood of deletion.

Comment: I guess the question should really be "why just that answer?".

Comment: @Bart With the answer almost certainly being, "that was the only one flagged, so the mod didn't know there were other answers that should be deleted"  It's a very solvable problem.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I assume as much.

Answer (score 10):

As Bart notes in a comment, I did make a mistake here; I *only* deleted that one answer, and not the others - and I did not consider closing the question.

The reason for that inconsistency is that I was handling it via a flag, so all I saw was a question that appeared to be asking for some specific info, and an answer that just contained a link - one broken, no less.

Comment: the front page of the project is down, yet the Github project is alive. And I have edited the answer months ago to reflect that.

Comment: The fact that one of the links is broken is actually one of the reasons we tend not to like link-only answers in the first place. Also; your link was to a project, and did not actually address the specific question being asked. I know that seems funny since *you* asked the question, but...

Comment: @Ken and for the record; the link to the project is probably a great comment to add to the question. Or, you could edit your answer to include some explanation directly relating to your question. Remember that people will find your question based on what you asked, and they'll be looking for specific answers.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the link to front page and left only the github link in there. I have also added a line of code how to retrieve the score. The library is small, I think thats all I can do to improve it, rest is up to you. :)

Comment: @Kave Ok; that's good enough for me. I would expound on it a little bit at some point (a *good* excuse for a bump!), but it definitely no longer qualifies for why it was originally flagged. Thanks!